# Foundation: Section + Clearing

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

[image]

Clearing works fine, but the "Photo" tab of Section **remains on the photo**.

I've just used examples code

**Sections:** http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html

**Clearing:** http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html

[image]

**Rails 4.0.0**

Comment: The problem is "z-index: 11;" for active tab. If I change to 10 it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in this way. Anyone knows something better?

**app.css**

```
 .section-container.auto > section.active > .title, .section-container.auto > .section.active > .title {
        z-index: 10;
    }
```